# Help with PHP echo syntax with JS quotes

Tags: php, javascript

Here's a snippet of my echo command:

```
echo 'onclick="derp(',$url,$image_dir,$file,')'
```

It currently outputs something like this:

```
onclick="derp(foobar)
```

But, I want it to output something like this:

```
onclick="derp('foobar')
```

Since PHP freaks out when you use quotes, I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'onclick="derp(\'',$url,$image_dir,$file,'\')';
```

Comment: alternate syntax  
echo "onclick=\"derp(',$url,image,$file')\"";

Comment: @Luke Miles If an answer was the solution to your problem, please accept it by clicking on the accept button next to the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "onclick=\"derp(',$url,$image_dir,$file,')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode the values properly:

```
$onclick = "derp(".json_encode($url.$image_dir.$file).")";
echo 'onclick="'.htmlspecialchars($onclick).'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'onclick="derp(', "'", $url, $image_dir, $file, "'", ')';
```